# How to call typescript function instead of javascript function from dotnetbrowser c# code?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, dotnetbrowser

I am trying to embed my angular app inside DotNetBrowser control inside a WPF application. I do not want to write javascript in my angular component and invoke the same from dot net browser c# code. Can I invoke the typescript component function instead of javascript function?

C# code for invoking typescipt function:-

```
JSValue returnValue =browserViewControl.Browser.ExecuteJavaScriptAndReturnValue("onGetAllCallBack");
            // Make sure that return value is a function.
            if (returnValue.IsFunction())
            {
                String val = "Hello World";
                returnValue.AsFunction().Invoke(null, val);
            }
```

Angular component:-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    let onGetAllCallBack: (para: string) => void;

    Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
    contextList = 'No Context Available!';
    onGetAllCallBack = function (pass: string): void {
        this.contextList = pass;
      };

    }
```

The above code

> `browserViewControl.Browser.ExecuteJavaScriptAndReturnValue("onGetAllCallBack");`
>   does not invoke the typescript function.Is it the right way to invoke
>   it?Can anyone help?

Comment: Show what the JavaScript would look like. I think you are misunderstanding scope.

Comment: Hi Aluan, Do I have to call typescript function from the Javascript function? And Javascript will be imported into Angular2 component. I am sorry for asking such basic questions but I am completely new to this.

Comment: It's all JavaScript. TypeScript is JavaScript. There is no interop between them whatsoever because they are both JavaScript.